# Dynamics CRM JavaScript Error Checking Popups

Tags: dynamics-crm, dynamics-crm-2015

I recently wrote some JavaScript that produced a null reference exception (only happens under certain circumstances).  In our Dev environment the typical "out of the box" Javascript popup message that would alert me to issue didn't show up.

When we pushed the web resource to QA the "out of the box" JavaScript error message was displayed .  I was wondering if there is a way that JavaScript error checking that produces these popups could have been turned off in our dev environment.

I am lost as to why the same code would show the out of the box error in one environment and not the other when the same reproduction steps were taken.

[Javascript error displayed in QA but not Dev](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sNaGc.png)

Comment: Is it actually producing the same error? Have you tried debugging the Javascript in the Dev environment, and verifying that it actually produces the null error and should show the popup?

Comment: It depends on your browser settings. For IE check the internet settings dialog, tab Advanced.

Comment: Please put a code for further investigation

Comment: Yes I have tried debugging in Dev and it should show the same error. I even went as far as trying to alert a variable that is not defined which would always throw an error and it threw the error in QA but not in Dev.

Comment: The issue with the Javascript itself has been fixed.  That wasn't my issue I knew how to fix that right away.  My issue is that I was never alerted to the script breaking in Dev since it seems like something is supressing the javascript error alerts.

Comment: As far as browser settings go I tested it both in QA and Dev using my machine and IE which would have the same browser settings.  I am starting to feel like there is something at the server level maybe a config or registry setting that is suppressing these messages.

Answer (score 0):

I can't see the image you've linked due to company firewall restrictions but I'm assuming it's the bult in error reporting dialog.

Your user record in the development environment may have error reporting turned off.

Within CRM:

1. Settings
2. Privacy Preferences
3. Error Reporting
4. Select the option "Ask the User for Permission..."

This will now show the prompt containing the stacktrace.  You can also use the browser developer tools to view any console output.

Comment: Yeah I thought that was the issue as well but that seems to only control the Send Error notification to Mircrosoft window and not the javascript alerts that are thrown that tell you more detail info such as when you have null references, etc...

Answer (score 0):

It is always better to check the existence of CRM fields in javascript before using the field.
for eg.

```
if(Xrm.Page.getAttribute("FIELD_NAME") && Xrm.Page.getAttribute("FIELD_NAME").getValue()) 
{
// Perform operation on Xrm.Page.getAttribute("FIELD_NAME")
}
```

Comment: Correct, I know what the javascript issue was and was able to fix immediately.  What I am confused about is why the popup only showed in QA and not my Dev environment.  The code deployed to both environments were identical.  I have even tried to alert a variable that doesn't exist which should throw an error message for sure and it does it in QA but not in Dev.